# Bootstrap confirmation dialog to delete something

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm with some problem here, and i can't find the solution anywhere... I've been lookin here for hours and nothing.

Ok, so, basically what i want to do is to display a table with a list of news (for a website i'm working on). Each news on this table has a unique ID and an option to exclude. I want to create a confirm dialog to exclude the news the user selected to delete. But i can't get the ID from the table, only the dialog.

I'm usin bootstrap modal to do it.
This is the code i have so far:

**Button inside the table (with the default ID to delete):**

```
<a class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-href="delete.php?id=23" ><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Delete</a>
```

Or

```
<a class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="23" ><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Excluir</a>
```

**Button inside the modal:**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a class="btn btn-success pointer" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Cancel</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger danger pointer" href="delete.php?ref=" ><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> CONFIRM</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
    removeBtn = $(this).find('.danger');

    removeBtn.attr('href', removeBtn.attr('href').replace(/(&|\?)ref=\d*/, '$1ref=' + id));

    $('#debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + removeBtn.attr('href') + '</strong>');
});

$('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong events for bootstrap.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage and go to events(just a little bit scroll down)

`show.bs.modal` - This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.

Comment: so, instead of using `$('#myModal').on('show', function() {`
i should use `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {` ?

Comment: Yes. No ```show``` event is bind to #myModal by bootstrap. Next time try log your events objects and variables, it's a good practice and saves you from many bugs.

Comment: I did this, but my url after i confirm the delet is this `delete.php?ref=` Still with no ID. I'm using the `show.bs.modal` also in the other function: `$('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show.bs.modal');`

Comment: Try using ```attr("data-id")``` instead of ```data()``` method to get value from attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but i'm trying to do what you said and i can't get the right results. Can you give me an answer with the code, so i can see it? I'm new to these things, so i'm still learning.